# Is de-extinction possible in the near future?

Tags: biology

I just read a news about an organization for [de-extinction of extincted animals](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/scientists-want-to-bring-some-animals-back-from-extinction-211102151.html), see also [here](http://longnow.org/revive/) and [here](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2013/03/19/your-de-extinction-questions-answered/). I searched internet to see if it is really a possible project, but i haven't found any estimate about its costs and its time frame. Of course, it may be possible in the next 2000 years. But my question is:

> Is de-extinction possible in the near future (so we can see the result in our life)?

Comment: You might find http://www.ted.com/talks/stewart_brand_the_dawn_of_de_extinction_are_you_ready.html interesting.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for the link. My question is more about the time frame of achieving this technology, which is not discussed in detail in those old answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been done recently:

http://inhabitat.com/scientists-bring-extinct-mouth-brooding-frog-back-to-life-after-30-years/

It seems to be more difficult the longer a species has been extinct.

Comment: I don't think the report confirms that it has done. It says

Comment: "A process called somatic cell nuclear transfer (SCNT) was applied to a batch of eggs that had been kept in a freezer over the last 40 years. Biologists deactivated the eggs from the distantly related great-barred frog, and swapped the nuclei with that of the gastric-brooding frog. Some of the resulting eggs began to spontaneously divide, growing into the embryo stage. While none of the embryos survived past a few days, genetic tests confirm that the little balls of life were in fact full of the genetic material from the extinct species.

Comment: We’re increasingly confident that the hurdles ahead are technological and not biological and that we will succeed."  The above sentences doesn't mean it's done yet.